# Persist data from the previous state while going back - Angular 1.4 UI Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

I have a web application wherein there are many states based on the URL change.
There is an `User Management` page (containing a search `Input` control) which lists the Users based on search results.

When clicking a particular `User`, the User details would get loaded through a different state. I put a `Button` to go back to the `User Management` page.

The requirement is to persist the search result in the `User Management` page when coming back from `User Detail` page.

Kindly help me achieve this requirement, without making new XHR to fetch the search lists again.

```
.state('userManagement', {
    url: '/user-management',
    templateUrl: 'components/userManagement/UserMgmt.view.html',
    controller: 'UserMgmtCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
  .state('userDetail', {
    url: '/user-detail/:userId',
    templateUrl: 'components/userManagement/UserDetail.view.html',
    controller: 'UserDetailCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
```

Should I have nested states or something to achieve this?

Comment: You should use a factory/service to persist data across states/views.

Comment: When you use the button to go back, are you doing a `$state.go()`? If so, you could simply pass back a search parameter to your userManagement state.

Comment: @Lex I'm new to routing so here is a silly question. Won't that require another XHR?

Comment: @Ohjay44 I can use services, that's an obvious answer but is there any feature within `state routing` to achieve this directly? That's the exact question.

Comment: You're right, it would. As Ohjay44 mentioned if you are looking to store the results you'd want to use a service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add resolves in your states to inject the stuff you want in your controllers.

Use an angular service to store your stuff because they are singletons, meaning they only get instantiated once, therefore the data stored in them is always the same.

```
.state('userManagement', {
    url: '/user-management',
    templateUrl: 'components/userManagement/UserMgmt.view.html',
    controller: 'UserMgmtCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        yourStuff: function (StorageService) {
            return StorageService.getStuff();
        } 
    }
})
.state('userDetail', {
    url: '/user-detail/:userId',
    templateUrl: 'components/userManagement/UserDetail.view.html',
    controller: 'UserDetailCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        yourStuff: function (StorageService) {
            return StorageService.getStuff();
        } 
    }
})

app.factory("StorageService", function () {
    var yourStuffStorage = {
        "initial": "stuff"
    };

    return {
          getStuff: getStuff,
          setStuff: setStuff
    };

    function getStuff () {
        return yourStuffStorage;
    }

    function setStuff (newStuff) {
        yourStuffStorage = angular.copy(newStuff); 
    }
})

app.controller("UserMgmtCtrl", function (yourStuff) {
    console.log("do stuff with your stuff 1", yourStuff);
});

app.controller("UserDetailCtrl", function (yourStuff) {
    console.log("do stuff with your stuff 2", yourStuff);
});
```

If you were wondering why didn't we inject the service and query for the data, that's because it's considered best practice in ui-router to fetch data (sometimes via promises) and pass the result to the controller, so that the state won't load before the data loads.

Hope this helps :)